# Parse text from MS Access memo field

Tags: parsing, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a MS Access 2013 memo field that I use to hold text versions of
email. Here is an example:

```
From: Simon Smith
To: Bob Brown
Date: 5/4/15 2:30PM
Subject: Draft Report 

Please find attached the draft report as discussed.
```

I want to extract the data (i.e. "Draft Report") from the email field "Subject:" from a memo field to a text field on an MS Access form.

Can anyone help?

Thankyou GM

Comment: In your research on this question did you come across the concepts of (1) using a custom Function (written in VBA) in an Access Query, (2) using the InStr() function to locate text in a string, (3) using the Mid() function to extract a portion of the string?

Comment: Thankyou for your advice Gord. I worked something out using InStr and Mid :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I have figured it out using Instr and Mid. Thankyou for your suggestion Gord. I'm sure there is better way to do it but it works!

```
Dim strStart As String
Dim strEnd As String

' figure out where the string starts
strStart = InStr(Me.EmailMemo, "Subject:") + 9

' figure out where the line ends by looking for a carriage return
strEnd = InStr(strStart, Me.EmailMemo, Chr(10))

' display the string
Me.EmailTitle = Mid(Me.EmailMemo, strStart, strEnd - strStart)
```